# SQL Stored procedures and error handling

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, stored-procedures

I use Stored procedures all the time. but i never used error handlers inside stored procedures. I just came to know about error handlers. I tried to do it in my stored procedures but i never got the error message in my application. i am giving my stored procedure below

```
ALTER PROCEDURE   [dbo].[E_AddDesignation]

    @Designation nvarchar(100),
    @Order int 

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @myRowCount int

    SELECT DesignationID FROM Designation WHERE (DesignationName = @Designation)
    SET @myRowCount=@@ROWCOUNT
    IF(@myRowCount ! = 0)
        BEGIN       
            RAISERROR('Already exists',5,1)
        END
    ELSE 
        BEGIN
            insert into Designation(DesignationName,DesignationOrder) values (@Designation,@Order)
            RAISERROR('Submitted Successfully',5,1)
        END 
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END
```

I am trying to call the storedprocedures and to get the error message like below.

```
Try            
            c.con.Open()
            c.cm = New SqlCommand("E_AddDesignation", c.con)
            c.cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            c.cm.Parameters.Add("@Designation", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Designation
            c.cm.Parameters.Add("@Order", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Order           
            c.cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            c.con.Close()
        Catch ex As SqlException
            Console.WriteLine(ex)
        End Try
```

i am done something wrong somewhere. please help me to to find out the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you're raising error with severity 10.

```
 RAISERROR('Already exists',5,1)
```

So SQLConnection will treat it as InfoMessage and not exception.  The InfoMessage event occurs when a message with a severity of 10 or less is returned by SQL Server. Messages that have a severity between 11 and 20 raise an error and messages that have a severity over 20 causes the connection to close. Please check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

You might want to check database error severities [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx)

You can wire up infomessage event as shown below:

```
// Assumes that connection represents a SqlConnection object.
   connection.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(OnInfoMessage);

protected static void OnInfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs args)
{
  foreach (SqlError err in args.Errors)
  {
   Console.WriteLine("The {0} has received a severity {1}, state {2} error number {3}\n" +
   "on line {4} of procedure {5} on server {6}:\n{7}",
   err.Source, err.Class, err.State, err.Number, err.LineNumber, 
   err.Procedure, err.Server, err.Message);
  }
}
```

For more information check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0hee08w%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

To handle exception in your stored procedure itself, you can use Try..Catch block from SQL Server 2005 onwards.

**Edit:** You may want to check [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321903) that shows

**HOW TO: Return Errors and Warnings from a SQL Server Stored Procedure in ADO.NET**

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You have specified a severity level of `5` (`RAISERROR('Already exists',5,1)`) which according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx) means

```
Informational messages that return status information or report errors
that are not severe. The Database Engine does not raise system errors with
severities of 0 through 9.
```

You should return `16`  which is the default severity level

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I believe it will be down to your use of `SET NOCOUNT ON;`.

Try moving the `SET NOCOUNT OFF;` line to the line immediately below your `SET @myRowCount=@@ROWCOUNT` line. Then the stored procedure should be able to return a value.

I seem to remember having a similar issue a few years ago.

---

Also as a side note you could replace the following chunk of code:

```
SELECT DesignationID FROM Designation WHERE (DesignationName = @Designation)
SET @myRowCount=@@ROWCOUNT
IF(@myRowCount ! = 0)
```

with a smaller (and in my opinion nicer) piece of code like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Designation WHERE DesignationName = @Designation)
```

I'm just mentioning this as I used to use the method your using for years until I found the `EXISTS` keyword!